# Insert data from a text file into a table in C#

Tags: c#, database, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have text file which looks like

```
word
love
book
...
...
```

and I have a table in my SQL Server. The table has a columm `column1`.

How can I insert data into `column1` from the text file in C# winform ??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I have added the answer. But please notise, next time before asking to make "all your job" show that you was trying something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I would start reading the file line by line and inserting the line values into a `List<string>`.

This can be done with a `StreamReader`. It is part of the `System.IO` - namespace.

```
List<string> myValues = new List<string>();
string line;    
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = 
   new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   myValues.Add(line);
}
```

Then open a DB-Connection to your DB via [OleDB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aa288452%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

And insert the values into your database via an `INSERT INTO` Statement.

For Example:

```
private void InsertMyValue(string myValue){
     dbconnection.Open();
     string setValues = "INSERT INTO YourTable(myColumn) VALUES ('" + myValue+ "');";
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(setValues, dbconnection);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     dbconnection.Close();
}
```

Then call the method in a `foreach` - clause:

```
foreach(string myLine in myValues){ //Go through the List with all the Lines
       dbconnection.InsertMyValue(myLine); //Get every item in the List and call the Insert-Method
}
```

Comment: Thank you for not just giving the full code solution.

Answer (score 0):

This one will work:

```
var a = StreamReader("file.txt");
List<String> words = new List<String>();
While(String line = a.ReadLine())
{
    context.someTable.Add(new someTable(){column1=line});
}
context.SaveChanges();
```